# node.js Child Process has timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

In short:
does the child_process automatically dies after certain time not being accessed for certain period( or is there anyway we can set this), or do we always have to explicitly kill the processes all the time?

in Long:
I am doing some decoding work, using `require('child_process').fork()`, when the first data comes in, i initialize a child, and as more data packets come in, i use the child to decode them( I send it in from client side),  when I see that the last data packet is decoded, I kill the child through `child.kill()`, this works perfectly well, but under certain scenarios, the streaming fails in between, though I show appropriate error in client side, I am scared that this would lead to memory leak in server as the child_process is never killed.

Comment: Yes, afaik you you need to explicitly kill the process if you encounter the error. Of course you could also implement a timeout in the child process to kill itself, but that might lead to a whole new set of problems.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to kill it in the error condition, I can't see anything in the docs suggesting otherwise, and it would be quite surprising behavior to terminate a process after an inactivity timeout without giving you control over the inactivity timeout. But I can't say that of my own certain knowledge. Separately: What's the *downside* of killing it in  your error condition? You spawned it, if you're done with it (whether because of an error or end-of-input), you should kill it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  the problem is, server wont know when the error occurs, it is something like, if network breaks, and client moves on, the server would still wait thinking that packets are coming, one solution is everytime a packet comes in, I create child and kill it once it decodes, but i think it would be expensive

Comment: @mido22: I misunderstood what you were saying about the error. So probably the best answer is for *you* to implement an inactivity timeout, server-side.